# How to manually set to unauthorized and redirect to custom page?

Tags: .net

I'm adding a custom unauthorized page to a web application. Based on a certain AD group users are in they are allowed to login, else they get redirected to a page that says they are unauthorized to use the application. The group is included in the token and I want to filter that in an if statement. I tried below options, but neither work.

This is my startup.cs file (removed some code for brevity):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.SlidingExpiration = false;
            options.Cookie.Name = "mvcimplicit";

        })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = (TokenValidatedContext c) =>
            {
                var token = c.SecurityToken;
                var name = c.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "name");
                var group = c.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "group");
                if (name != null && group != null)
                {
                    if (!group.ToString().Contains("GROUP_ONE"))
                    {
                        // It hits these lines, but doesn't redirect
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Access denied!");
                        c.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        c.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/NoAccess.cshtml");
                    }
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // This doesn't redirect either
    app.UseStatusCodePages(context => {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/NoAccess.cshtml");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve a redirection for unauthorized users based on token info?

Comment: Create some user profile "authAdmin" in your AD, which will call AD. After this use this manual https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/active-directory-and-net/ Just to take user from AD by username using authAdmin credentials and check is user has required group.

Comment: I can't access the AD. It's managed elsewhere. They just send me the group name and said it's possible to authorize based on group. Is it?

Comment: Who send you group name? You need users list in that group from AD. You will not authorize anybody if don't have an access to AD or if you don't know which usernames in that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a Role based on the group from the token.
Added this to startup.cs:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = (TokenValidatedContext c) =>
    {
        var token = c.SecurityToken;
        var name = c.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "name");
        var group = c.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "group");
        if (name != null && group != null)
        {
            // Only users present in this AD group are allowed access to the web app
            if (group.ToString().Contains("GROUP_ONE"))
            {
                var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)c.Principal.Identity;
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Token NOT validated for user");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

And then handle the redirect in the HomeController based on this Role:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // If user does not have the role of Admin, redirect to NoAccess page
        if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UnAuthorized");
        }

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult UnAuthorized()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Shared/NoAccess.cshtml");
    }
}
```